# How do i check if string exists in Tlist whether its lower or uppercase

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I created a function to check if string exits inside Tlist here is my code

```
function FindDtataLIST(namestring: String): BOOLEAN;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to Listofdata.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if TData(Listofdata.Items[I]).Name = namestring then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

but there is some pitfalls i am stick with , if my `listofdata` have string with capital letter as example  : `'MaRtiN'`  and name string equal small letter as example : `martin` result did not return to True i want to check

`if FindDtataLIST(namestring) = True` whenever if namestring exist with some capital letters or small

Comment: Use [`SysUtils.SameText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.SameText) for that.

Comment: @whosrdaddy `SameText` is not locale-aware. So: `SameText('Á', 'á') = False`

Comment: both suggestion helps thank you very much

Comment: You might consider a generic container to avoid the risky casting and the need to manage memory manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to check if both strings are equal, you can use [`AnsiSameText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiSameText):

```
function FindDtataLIST(namestring: String): BOOLEAN;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to Listofdata.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if AnsiSameText(TData(Listofdata.Items[I]).Name, namestring) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @whosrdaddy I'm still in old D7, so I can't test for sure, but I believe you're wrong: http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200907/0907304462.html

Comment: The name is a bit misleading, but AnsiSameText has an UnicodeString overload. So AnsiSameText is what you're supposed to use.

Comment: Also, see DH's answer here (talks about the mess with the `Ansi`prefix): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444579/why-ansisametext-is-not-ansi

Answer (score -2):

Use "uppercase"

```
function FindDtataLIST(namestring: String): BOOLEAN;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to Listofdata.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if uppercase(TData(Listofdata.Items[I]).Name) = uppercase(namestring) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Didn't test it, hope this helps...

Comment: No need for uppercase, (ansi)sametext is needed, that's all