# In Delphi is there a double quote string function?

Tags: string, delphi, double-quotes

I'm aware of the `QuotedStr` function, but is there a similar function for double quoting for example

```
for i := 0 to List.count - 1 do
begin
  List[i] := DoubleQuotedStr(List[i]);
end;
```

Comment: Search for it. If it exists it's in the same place. If not, it's not hard to write.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`AnsiQuotedStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiQuotedStr) which accepts a quote character:

```
List[i] := AnsiQuotedStr(List[i], '"');
```

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiQuotedStr):

> ```
> function AnsiQuotedStr(const S: string; Quote: Char): string;
> ```
>
> ....
>
> Use AnsiQuotedStr to convert a string (S) to a quoted string, using the provided Quote character. A Quote character is inserted at the beginning and end of S, and each Quote character in the string is doubled.

Comment: Does this support Unicode correctly?  It seems to work in my limited testing, but could a byte of a code point be incorrectly interpreted as  a double-quote?

Comment: Yes it supports Unicode. The naming is confusing, but the Ansi prefix means that it is locale aware. Not particularly relevant for this particular function as it happens. There are no bytes here. This is UTF-16. That's two bytes per character element. Either one or two character elements per code point.

Comment: For instance, read the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444579/why-ansisametext-is-not-ansi

Comment: I've looked through the code for `AnsiQuotedStr`, it looks like it does support Unicode despite its unhelpful naming, thanks again David.

Answer (score 5):

In the newer Delphi versions, if you include `System.SysUtils`, you can use the string helper function [TStringHelper.QuotedString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.QuotedString) with parameter `'"'`:

```
'Test'.QuotedString('"')
```

This will return `"Test"`.

I made a small unit test for it:

```
uses 
  System.SysUtils, DUnitX.TestFramework;

(...)

procedure TStringFunctionsTests.TestWithQuotedString;
var
  TestString: string;
  ExpectedResult: string;
  TestResult: string;
begin
  TestString := 'ABC';
  ExpectedResult := '"ABC"';
  TestResult := TestString.QuotedString('"');
  Assert.AreEqual(TestResult, ExpectedResult);
end;
```